# Threading and Locking Resources

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I'm hoping to get some help understanding a concept. I apologize for improper use of terminology. I am new to OOP, so please bear with me.

Here's some pseudocode to display the issue:

```
public MyClass
{
    myClass singleton; //singleton object of myClass (only one instance created)
    myCollection; //list or array
    private object _lock;

    public myFunction()
    {
        lock(myCollection) //or do I use lock(_lock)?
        {
            try
            {
                //modifies my collection
            }
            catch
            {
                //exception
            }
        }
    }

    public secondFunction()
    {
        //modify my collection
    }

    public getMyCollection()
    {
        return myCollection;
    }

}
```

Now let's assume we have two objects on separate threads from classA and classB (I'll call these objects objA and objB) that are trying access MyClass.

**1)** If objA is using myFunction, I understand that objB won't be able to use myFunction at the same time due to the lock.

However, can objB use secondFunction()? 
Or does the lock on myFunction() protect myCollection from being modified until the lock is released?

If the above question is true: If objA is using myFunction(), and objB is trying to use secondFunction(), will the objB thread wait until the lock is released?

**2)** What is the better convention? 
lock(_lock) 
or
lock(myCollection)

**3)** If I use lock(_lock), in myfunction(), will it still protect myCollection from being accessed in secondFunction()?

Thank you for your time and patience.

Comment: 1) You need to lock any time the collection is modified, including `secondFunction`, 2) `lock(_lock)` is better, 3) no. Locks aren't magical. They know nothing about your collection or what goes on inside of them so it's impossible for them to help your `secondFunction()`.

Comment: So when you actually ran that code, what actually happened?  You could answer all of those questions by just running the code and observing the result.

Comment: @Servy _"and observing the result"_ - not with threading. That will never be conclusive.

Comment: @itsme86 Thanks for your response! My doubts have been cleared.

Comment: @Servy: I wasn't quite understanding the results of the code

Comment: @HenkHolterman It would be a perfectly fine solution for a case like this.  Either the method can be called, or it can't.  There are certainly lots of more complex situations that are not easily tested, but this isn't one of them.

Comment: @Tim So what results did you actually get when you ran it, and what about them didn't you understand?

Comment: @Servy Essentially, this pseudo code is different from my actual code. In my actual code, myFunction() adds "3" to myList ~500 times. secondFunction() adds "4" to myList ~500 times. I was expecting secondFunction() to stop adding "4" to myList, and give priority to myFunction() when it locked the object. I was assuming locks were magical, and everyone's comments here showed me my assumptions were wrong.

Comment: @Tim Okay, so when you ran that code, what was the result?  Did it do the thing that you were thinking it would do, or not?  How did those results fail to answer your questions?

Comment: @Servy If I recall, 4 didn't always give priority to 3 like I thought it would. So rather than making more blind assumptions about locks and threading, I decided to ask here for clarification.

Comment: @Tim So, based on your tests, you already knew that both functions were allowed to run at the same time, and that they were able to interact with the collection when one of them had the lock and the other didn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If objA is using myFunction, I understand that objB won't be able to use myFunction at the same time due to the lock.

To be clear: objA and objB here is a shorthand for "called on thread A" and "called on thread B".

Your statement is basically correct; we can be more crisp and say that if thread A *acquires the lock* then thread B's attempt to acquire the lock will *block* until such a time as thread A releases the lock.

Note also that there is no guarantee that locks are fair.  If thread C attempts to acquire the lock after thread B, there is no guarantee that thread B gets it when thread A releases it.  Thread C can go first.

Think about it like this. You've got a desert. In the middle of the desert is a bathtub. There are no walls. There is a door standing beside the bathtub. The door has a lock.  The rules are: if you want to use the bathtub and the door is unlocked, lock the door, take a bath, unlock the door. If you want to use the bathtub and the door is locked, wait until it is unlocked.  If there are multiple people waiting, then one is chosen to win the race to the tub by some unspecified mechanism.

> However, can objB use secondFunction()?

Sure.  This would be violating the rules and hopping into the tub whether or not the door is locked. Remember, there are no walls.

> Or does the lock on myFunction() protect myCollection from being modified until the lock is released?

Not at all. **Nothing whatsoever stops myCollection from being modified except putting the *same* lock around every place it can be modified**.  That is, requiring everyone to wait by the door if they want to use the tub.

> If objA is using myFunction(), and objB is trying to use secondFunction(), will the objB thread wait until the lock is released?

No; there's no lock in secondFunction.

Again, go back to the fundamentals.  A lock may be **acquired** by a thread and it may be **released** by the thread that acquired it.  A lock can be acquired many times by the same thread without releasing it.  Once all the acquires have a corresponding release, the lock is free to be acquired by any other thread.

For your purposes right now, *that's it*.  Locks are very, very simple. You acquire them, if you can't acquire them you block until you can, and once you have acquired a lock you need to release it shortly after to give someone else a turn.

There are far more complex ways to use locks, but start with the basics.

> What is the better convention? lock(_lock) or lock(myCollection)

**Always lock on a purpose-built object that is private and used for nothing other than locking**.  There are a great many ways in which things can go horribly wrong if you deviate from this best practice.

In particular never ever ever lock on a `Type`, on a `string`, or on `this`.

> If I use lock(_lock), in myfunction(), will it still protect myCollection from being accessed in secondFunction()?

No.  Again, go back to the definition of what a lock does.  A lock statement *attempts to acquire the lock*.  That's *all* that it does.  If you have some other function somewhere else that doesn't acquire the lock when it needs to, well, that's a bug. If that sounds like an easy bug to write, *it is*.

Multithreading is **super hard**, and if you're not careful you can easily end up with lots of people in the tub at the same time.  Which is less fun than it sounds, because none of them agree on whether the water should be running or not, and maybe some of them are trying to clean that tub while there are people in it, and it's a mess that crashes your process and loses your user's data.

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed response Eric. Going back to your statement: "Note also that there is no guarantee that locks are fair. If thread C attempts to acquire the lock after thread B, there is no guarantee that thread B gets it when thread A releases it. Thread C can go first" which keyword or mechanism would I use to give more priority to Thread B instead of Thread C?

Comment: @Tim: Typing "C# thread priority" into any search engine will answer your question. That said: priority is only a suggestion.  If the operating system *always* gave the critsec to the highpri thread then you could very easily end up with a starved thread that waits forever even though the critsec is being frequently released. Trust the OS to schedule your threads. But better still is **use the task parallel library and let it handle your workers for you**.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: @Tim: I cannot emphasize enough that *multithreading is very hard on modern hardware*. Multithreading gives you a world where *you must assume that all memory is being modified unless something is keeping it still*. It gives you a world where *two threads can disagree as to the order in which variables were mutated*. Basically, everything you think you know about your program can be wrong.  Do not fall into the trap of thinking that any part of this is easy.

Comment: @Tim: Oh, but it gets worse. The primary tool we give you to tame this problem is the lock, which is a horrid tool; it requires you to have **global knowledge of all locks in the program** in order to use it correctly, so your usual technique of composing small correct solutions to small problems into large correct solutions of large problems no longer works.  My advice is to avoid multithreading as much as possible.

Comment: @Tim: An exercise: implement `class Counter` with public members `public Counter(); public int Points { get; } public void Transfer(int count, Counter other);` Every counter starts at 100 points; a counter may gain points only by transferring them away from another counter, a counter never goes below 0 or above 1000 points, and *any method can be called from any thread on any counter*.  You must implement this type so that it cannot possibly violate the given invariants, and...

Comment: ... here's the hard part: (1) *If counter A and counter B are transferring points right now, that must not cause any method of counter C that does not involve A or B to block*, and (2) there is no way for counters to end up "deadlocked", where, say, thread 1 is waiting for thread 2 to exit a lock, and thread 2 is waiting for thread 1 to exit a lock.  This seems like it ought to be a very simple problem. It is not.

Comment: @EricLippert: Your spec is incomplete.  You haven't specified what happens if a transfer is made that overflows a counter.  The problem is an order of magnitude easier with a spec like, "If B overflows, set B to 1000 and A still loses `count`."

Comment: @Brian: If the transfer would result in an illegal state then the transfer operation fails.  The invariant we want to maintain is that points are zero sum: if there are 100 players then there are 10000 points to distribute, and no one ever gains a point without someone else losing one.

Comment: I mean, this shouldn't be a hard problem right? In banking you make a withdrawal from one account, you credit another account, and doing so does not delay any transaction in any unrelated account. You end up with the same total amount of money you started with, just in different accounts. It's utterly trivial to get this right on one thread, but attempting to solve this simple problem on multiple threads clearly illustrates just how hard multithreading is to get right.

Comment: @EricLippert: "The primary tool we give you to tame this problem is the lock, which is a horrid tool". You use locks only if you have to share the same mutable resources among multiple threads. You can still have effective multi-threading without sharing resources, e.g. by using message passing and queues. In this case the multi-threading implementation is much more simple to understand and maintain.

Comment: @LucaCremonesi: Absolutely. I dearly wish that early lessons on multithreading for novices would be about process calculus, actor model, and so on. Trying to maintain correctness with multiple threads of control in a world with mutable state is too hard.

Comment: @EricLippert: In regards to your exercise: I'm not even sure whether the problem is even solvable.  That says something about the difficulty of the problem, but it's also annoying.  Are you suggest a resource which discusses this problem? It seems like the kind of problem that would interest both researchers and developers.  I'll note that the bank's solution to the problem is to violate most of the constraints.  In addition to heavy centralization (Counter C can block counters A and B), banks relax the zero sum invariant in favor of rollbacks (a failed A->B transfer will temporarily drop A).

Comment: I'll note that I'm aware of discussions of similar problems, but they usually add the additional complexity of transmission delays/failure into the mix, which has already been proven unsolvable  (e.g., things like CAP theorem and PACELC theorem).

Comment: @Brian: I don't know of a good solution to this problem that uses locks. Software Transactional Memory can solve this problem without deadlocks in a fairly straightforward way, but at significant performance cost over normal memory access.

Comment: @EricLippert: Briefly investigating STM via wikipedia, I'm seeing that common implementations either violate violate your constraint, "Counter C can't block a transfer between A and B" or instead cheat by allowing transactions to fail due to timing issues (i.e., transactions can fail even though the invariants in the spec are not violated).